# How to include these requirements in my database design?

Tags: sql, database-design

I am developing an intranet application for my company. The company has a complicated structure in which there are many business lines, departments, divisions, units and groups. I have to take care of all of these things. Some employees work under department level, some of them work under unit level and so on. The problem now is with database design. I am confused about how to design the database. At the beginning, I decided to design it as following:

```
Employees: Username, Name, Title, OrgCode
Departments: OrgCode, Name
Divisions: OrgCode, Name
Units: OrgCode, Name
```

but the problem as I said before, some employees are working under departments, so how to make relations between all of these tables. Is it possible to have OrgCode in Employees table as a foreign key to OrgCode in Departments, Divisions and Units tables?

**Could you please recommend me how to design it?**

**UPDATE:**
@wizzardz put a nice database design. All what I need now is to have an example of data that fit this database design
Here's a set of data that I am using in the database: 
let us assume that we have Employee with the following information:
Username: JohnA
Name: John
Title: Engineer
OrgCode: AA

And let us assume we have department AA, how I will distribute this data into the database design?

Comment: how many departments are there?

Comment: Storing the OrgCode in the employees table means that each employee can belong to only one department at a time; some employees may belong to more than one department, and you're not storing any history of people moving from department to department.

Comment: The employee can work for only one department. But he can move from that department to another department. So which design is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a design something like this

rather than going for  separate tables for Departments, Divisions etc try to store them in a single table with a TypeId to distingush Departments , Divisitions etc.

Could you try a design like this

[image]

In the Level table you need to enter the values like 'Deparments,Divisions', Groups, etc (By keeping it in a separate table you can handle any future addition of new levels by your organisation.)

In the OrganisationLevels table you need to store Department Names,Division Name, GroupName etc.

The Employee table has a forigen key reference with the table Organisation level, that will store which Level an employee is working in the organisation.

If you wants to store the work history of a particular employee/ there is a chance that an employee can be moves to one level to another I would suggest you to go for this design

[image]

Sample data wrt the design

**Level**

```
 Id  LevelType  
 1    Department
 2    Division
 3    Group
```

**OrganisationLevels**

```
Id Name LevelId Parent*(Give a proper name to this column)*
13  AA    1       NULL
.
.
21  B     2        13 (This column refer to the Id of department it belongs to.)
```

**Employees**

```
Id UserName Name   Title 
 110  JohnA    John   Engineer
```

**EmployeeWorkDetails**

```
Id  EmployeeId OrganisationLevelId StartDate  EndDate IsActive
271    110           13            20/09/2011   NULL     true
```

***OrgCode from the Employee Table can be removed, because I thought it is the employee code of the employee with that organisation.***

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please elaborate more on this by examples? Please have a look at my updated question. Becuase I don't know how to distribute divisions and departments into your database design.

Comment: @TechLover :- I have updated my answer with some sample data. See whether it helps.

Comment: Just one more question: **how to determine that this division belongs to this department?** For example, how to know that Division B belongs to Department AA?

Comment: @TechLover: then you will have to add a new column in the table **OrganisationLevels** to link the Department and Divisions within the table, I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Employees: Username, Name, Title, OrgCode
Departments: OrgCode, Name
Divisions: OrgCode, Name
Units: OrgCode, Name
```

To the above mentioned DB design, have one more table called Org containing OrgCode and another column as type (which we give insights on which type of org is it i.e. Departments,Divisions and Units)

then you can have employee table's OrgCode to have refer the OrgCode of Org table(parent-child relationship).

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this? I could not understand what you meant

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you learn the difference between analysis and design.  When you design a database, you are inventing tables, columns and constraints that will affect how the data is stored and retrieved.  You are concerned with ease of update and query, including operations you will learn about later.

When you analyze the data requirements, you aren't engaged in inventing things, you are engaged in discovering things.  And the things you are discovering are things about the "real world" the subject matter is supposed to represent.  You break the subject matter down into "entities" and relationships among those entities.  Then you relate every value stored in the database to an instance of an attribute, and every attribute to some aspect of either an entity or a relationship.  This results in a conceptual model.

In your case, the relationships between employees, departments, units, etc. sound quite complex.  It's worth quite a bit of effort to come up with a model  that reflects this complex reality accurately.

Once you have a good conceptual model, you can create SQL tables, columns, and constraints that adequately represent the conceptual model.  This involves design skills that can be learned.  But if you have a lousy conceptual model, you're doomed, no matter how good you are at design.